# Why all terminal text editors could stop working (AWS EC2 Ubuntu 16.04)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, aws, amazon-ec2

Maybe stupid question. But I'll try.

Can't open any files by any text editors (vi/vim/nano/less/touch) after restart OS (AWS EC2/Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS). But cat and tail still work.

I don't see any related problems in logs.
But boot logs contains following errors:

```
    Apr  4 21:02:32 xxx systemd[392]: keyboard-setup.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/bin/loadkeys: Exec format error
....
    Apr  4 xxx systemd[411]: resolvconf.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /bin/touch: Exec format error
....
    Apr  4 xxx systemd[798]: cloud-init-local.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /bin/touch: Exec format error
```

Any ideas?

Added:

@berndbausch Thank you for your answer. But unfortunately, I have only the following for all editors:

```
# strace -i vim 1.txt
[00007f44c1be17f7] execve("/usr/bin/vim", ["vim", "1.txt"], [/* 28 vars */]) = -1 
ENOEXEC (Exec format error)
[00007f44c1c0c380] write(2, "strace: exec: Exec format error\n", 32strace: exec: 
Exec format error
) = 32
[00007f44c1be17c8] exit_group(1)        = ?
[????????????????] +++ exited with 1 +++
```

Comment: What do you mean? What happens when you run, for example, `vim mytextfile` or `vim /etc/group`? By the way, I would not call `touch` or `less` text editors.

Comment: Looks like your filesystem is corrupt.  16.04 has also reached end of life and is no longer supported, so you should probably rebuild the machine.

Comment: @berndbausch nothing ... no errors, no any messages.

Comment: @psusi yes, it looks like disk issue. But I have to restore functionality before moving to new OS.

Comment: You say nothing happens? This means that you type vim myfile, then ENTER, then you get your prompt back? If so, try `strace vim myfile` to see the system calls made by `vim`. Perhaps there is a problem with some shared library. For example, if the standard shared library is incompatible with the vim binary, vim can't even output an error message. You could also check the nature of the vim binary - find out where it is (`type vim`) then use the `file` command to check it out.

Comment: `Exec format error` usually means you're trying to run an executable not supported by your architecture.  Have you recently installed software for the wrong architecture (e.g. programs compiled for ARM on an AMD64 system)?

Comment: @Kusalananda not at all. I haven't set up anything on this server anything since 2019. And I tried running "strace" on a snapshot from February 2020 ... and it's all ok for that state.